# Automate installation of CentOS 6.4 -minimal with kickstart on a DVD

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to automate installation of CentOS 6.4 -minimal with kickstart on a DVD

Below is my kick start that was auto generated by anaconda

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.

#version=DEVEL
install
cdrom
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --onboot no --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --noipv6
rootpw --iscrypted $6$.tHtXJMs5GEzyQRm$52EX5ue3UuFC/zgencUbxuvwHXIPDuLmllkuNs4NRq7/Wa7FsI8ICxwPDsy/KnzSaUfEqfBROLAv0tPMksOhA1
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc America/New_York
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"

repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=cdrom:sr0 --cost=100

%packages --nobase
@core
%end

============================================================
```

The problem happens when the `ks.cfg` tries to install packages from Repo that is in DVD

The error I'm getting:

```
Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to a missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correctly generated.

cannot find a valid baseurl for repo:CentOS

============================================================
```

If this a bug, is there any other way to automate the installation ?

Is there any alternate solution to Automate the CentOS6.4 minimal?

I have tried removing the line

```
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=cdrom:sr0 --cost=100
```

Problem still persists

Then I tried changing to something like this

```
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=file:///mnt/source--cost=100
```

Problem still persists

What am i missing to include .... ???

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem today, but after commenting the line it worked :)

```
#repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=cdrom:sr1 --cost=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use system-config-kickstart gui tool for creating your own file and then use mkisofs to create your own iso too.

http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sag-en-4/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html

The above link would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: I used the system-config-kickstart gui tool . the problem remains the same when it comes to a point to install packages --- it throws an error which says ----> "Unable to read group information from the repositories. This is a problem with the generation of your install tree."

Comment: on the tty3 console i also see this error Yum.Base: Failed to add groups file to repository: anaconda-CentOS-201303020136.i386 -None

Comment: Hi feels that when you are using creatrepo use -g option and appropriate comps.xml file you can check more here on http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=180440

Comment: This howto helped me build the iso http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/130-building-a-custom-centos-6-kickstart-disc-part-3

Comment: have followed the steps starting from 6.4 centos. It starts, I input the linux line but it comes out the cdrom is not found and it gets stuck. In the terminal F3 I see copy the ks, check the cdrom, and then eject it.
Any suggestions? I pretty sure is a simple matter but it is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

From the [RHEL 7 Kickstart documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#sect-kickstart-commands):

```
    url     Install from an installation tree on a remote server via FTP, HTTP, or HTTPS.
    --url=          - The location to install from. Supported protocols are HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and file.
    --mirrorlist=   - The mirror URL to install from.
    --proxy=        - Specify an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP proxy to use while performing the installation.
    --noverifyssl   - Disable SSL verification when connecting to an HTTPS server.
```

You have to set `url` property, like:

```
    url --url=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/
```

There are a handful of [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) templates that leverages kickstart scripts to create Centos VMs. One of those is the [Bento Project](https://github.com/opscode/bento).

Answer (score 0):

You did not have a space between the second and third parameter:

repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/--cost=100

Correct:
repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/ --cost=100